# Queries for cyclic proportional assignment of work to hosts

Tags: c++, algorithm, partitioning, distributed-computing, deterministic

Consider `M` pieces of work distributed over `N` hosts in a cyclic way where each host must get the amount of work proportional to its speed. Without proportions, this is implemented as:

```
int64_t AssignWorkToHost(const int64_t i_work) {
  return i_work % N;
}
```

Proportions are weights `p[i]` that sum up to `1.0`, so that `i`-th host must get more or less `p[i]*M` pieces of work.

`M` is so large that storing `M` values doesn't fit in the memory of a single host (but a solution where it fits would be of interest too). `N` can be as large as 10 000. Ideally each host must store no more than `O(M/N)` values and the computational complexity of `AssignWorkToHost()` should be no more than `O(N)`. Preprocessing is fine. The algorithm should be deterministic, meaning that each process within the distributed group must get the same assignment of work to hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a [priority queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) storing pairs of `(estimated processing time, worker)` with a custom comparator that compares in that order.

In pseudo-code, the body of assign to work looks like this:

```
(estimated_time, i) = queue.pop()
queue.push((estimated_time + worker_time[i], i))
return i
```

This is deterministic, requires `O(N)` memory, and each assignment takes time `O(log(N))`.

Of course you set `worker_time[i] = 1.0/worker_speed[i]` and now how much worker `i` gets assigned is proportional to its speed.

---

For a query interface, we can avoid replaying all history by the simple trick of reconstructing a single point in history, then playing it forward.  For that, at the time `(i_work-1)/total_speed` *no more than* `i_work-1` can have been produced.  Also, *no less than* `i_work-N` can have been produced.  (Why? Each worker has failed to produce a fraction < 1 of the theoretical `elapsed_time / worker_speed[i]` limit.  Therefore `N` workers have produced under `N` fewer than that theoretical limit.  Since it has to be an integer, that puts it at most `N-1` behind.  And `i_work-1 - (N-1) = i_work-N`.)  At that time, for each worker, we know how many that worker has produced, and we know when it next will produce another unit.

This is sufficient to produce the priority queue as of that moment of time.  Then we play it forward.  In no more than `N` steps, the `k`'th will pop out, correctly assigned.

Total running time for the query version is `O(N log(N))`.  And as the saying goes, "For all intents and purposes, `log(N)` is a constant.  For Google it is a somewhat larger constant."

(At the expense of considerably more complexity, I think you can make the query interface truly `O(N)`.)

In pseudo-code that is almost valid Python:

```
total_worker_speed = sum(1/t for t in worker_time)
t = (i_work-1) / total_worker_speed
total_done = 0
todo = []
for i in 0..count_workers:
    # At time t, this is how many are left.
    done = floor(t/worker_time[i])
    # This is how long until this worker produces the next unit
    time_left = (done+1)*worker_time[i] - t
    todo.push([time_left, i])
    total_done += done

queue = heapify(todo) # turning array into priority queue is O(N)
while total_done < iwork:
    # Get the next one.
    (estimated_time, i) = queue.pop()
    queue.push((estimated_time + worker_time[i], i))
    total_done += 1

# i now has the job that produced the iwork job.
return i
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, for query-like interface I don't see a way to use less than `O(M)` memory. Please, see `AssignWorkToHost()` in my question: it allows querying in arbitrary order for which host a piece of work is assigned to.

Comment: @SergeRogatch I added an explanation of how to create a query interface.  But given how expensive the query interface is, to whatever extent possible it would be good to use the incremental approach where possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting the algorithm. Can you write (pseudo)-code for the query function? I can't avoid it because the pieces of work are not assigned sequentially, for some of them there can be no query, etc.

Comment: @SergeRogatch I added commented pseudocode.